# Need a way to optimize the slow SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm running an update query / sub-query on mySQL server and it takes 12 minutes to finish and I think it is not optimize enough.

Could someone think about anyway to optimize it, so it can run faster?

Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE `TABLE_1` C
INNER JOIN(

    SELECT Cust_No,

    #current year sales

    (SELECT SUM(`Sales`)
    FROM `TABLE_2`
    WHERE Year = 2016
        AND Cust_No = p.Cust_No
    ) as CY_TOTAL_SALES,

    # Get previou year sales

        (SELECT SUM(`Sales`)
    FROM `TABLE_2`
    WHERE Year = 2015
        AND Cust_No = p.Cust_No
    ) as PY_TOTAL_SALES

    FROM `TABLE_2` p
    WHERE Year >= 2015
        AND Year <= 2016

) AS A ON C.`customer_number` = A.Cust_No
    SET C.CY_TOTAL_SALES = A.CY_TOTAL_SALES,
        C.PY_TOTAL_SALES = A.PY_TOTAL_SALES;
```

TABLE_1 contains 28,000 records ( customer_number field is unique and has indexed built)

TABLE_2 contains 250,000 records ( Cust_No is not unique,but has indexed built)

What it does is update TABLE_1 by joining Table_2 and use sub-query to sum up the total sales value for both years in TABLE_2 and then update the value back to TABLE_1 WHERE TABLE_1 customr number is matched with TABLE_2 Cust_no.

Comment: Run the query with `EXPLAIN ` and post the output.  this will show what part of the query are expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of a couple of possible solutions.

**Method one**

Do just one subquery, don't do any correlated subqueries, and sum conditionally based on the year.

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 C
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Cust_No, 
    SUM(IF(Year=2015, Sales, 0)) AS PY_TOTAL_SALES,
    SUM(IF(Year=2016, Sales, 0)) AS CY_TOTAL_SALES
  FROM TABLE_2
  WHERE Year IN (2015, 2016)
  GROUP BY Cust_No
) AS S ON C.customer_number = S.Cust_No
SET C.PY_TOTAL_SALES = S.PY_TOTAL_SALES,
    C.CY_TOTAL_SALES = S.CY_TOTAL_SALES;
```

**Method two**

Do no subqueries at all.

First, zero out the total sales for all customers:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 C
SET C.CY_TOTAL_SALES = 0,
    C.PY_TOTAL_SALES = 0;
```

Then do a join without using any subqueries or `SUM()` calls, and add each sale figure one at a time to the total sales for the customer.

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 AS C
INNER JOIN TABLE_2 AS S ON C.customer_number = S.Cust_No
SET C.CY_TOTAL_SALES = C.CY_TOTAL_SALES + IF(S.Year=2016, S.Sales, 0)
    C.PY_TOTAL_SALES = C.PY_TOTAL_SALES + IF(S.Year=2015, S.Sales, 0)
WHERE S.Year IN (2015, 2016);
```

For both of these solutions, you'll want an index in TABLE_2 on the columns (Cust_No, Year, Sales).

---

In the meantime, I can explain a bit why your original query is so slow. Your subquery reads TABLE_2, which you say has 250,000 rows (I'll assume all the rows are in 2015-2016), and for each row it calculates the total sales for the corresponding customer. This means it calculates the same sums many times for each customer.

You're running 500,000 correlated subqueries! It's actually a miracle it only takes 12 minutes.

As it's doing this, it saves this entire result in a 250,000 row temporary table because of the subquery.

Then it joins the temporary table to TABLE_1, and for each customer sets the CY_TOTAL_SALES and PY_TOTAL_SALES. You don't know it, but it's setting the same totals many times for each customer.

Comment: Thanks and will try out your solutions and see.

Comment: Hi Bill,  Thanks for the detail explanation and the method one is working the best only take 1.2 second. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comment because of new user reputation.

Without seeing the tables structures and the current indexes will be hard to tell how to optimize your current query.
Please edit your question to include the table structure (`show create table`).

Comment: Thanks for your response, why the table structure make different? TABLE_1 has 98 fields and the the Customer_Number is set as varchar(20) , TABLE_2 has 25 fields, the field cust_no set as varchar(20) as well. Both tables has about 10 different indexes on different fields.

Comment: I see you guys got a "better" variant - and i agree with Bill on the query. I guess i'm more of a visual guy and wanted to play with this on my end before giving an answer.

Comment: Also the explain of that query could have tell you where the slowest part of the query is. That's the most helpful information that you need to use when debugging query performance - always include that too!